how to set the dump file path when using jemalloc
I have already using jemalloc to dump memory in Rust, the dump works fine. But I want to set the dump file path. This is the jemalloc conf look like:
ENV MALLOC_CONF="prof:true,lg_prof_interval:24"

the dump file will generate in the project folder like this:
root@texhub-server-service-67c7bbb866-ftktz:/app# ls -alh
total 304M
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Jul 27 07:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   50 Jul 27 07:20 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25K Jul 27 07:20 jeprof.1.0.i0.heap
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25K Jul 27 07:20 jeprof.1.1.i1.heap
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25K Jul 27 07:28 jeprof.1.10.i10.heap
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25K Jul 27 07:29 jeprof.1.11.i11.heap
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25K Jul 27 07:30 jeprof.1.12.i12.heap
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25K Jul 27 07:31 jeprof.1.13.i13.heap
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25K Jul 27 07:21 jeprof.1.2.i2.heap
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25K Jul 27 07:22 jeprof.1.3.i3.heap
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25K Jul 27 07:23 jeprof.1.4.i4.heap
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25K Jul 27 07:23 jeprof.1.5.i5.heap
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25K Jul 27 07:24 jeprof.1.6.i6.heap
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25K Jul 27 07:25 jeprof.1.7.i7.heap
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25K Jul 27 07:26 jeprof.1.8.i8.heap
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25K Jul 27 07:27 jeprof.1.9.i9.heap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 188K Jul 27 07:09 libsynctex_parser.so
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   40 Jul 27 07:20 log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  496 Jul 23 14:03 log4rs.yaml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  900 Jul 23 14:03 settings.toml
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 303M Jul 27 07:16 texhub-server

how to change the dump path to /opt/data/? I have tried to read the manual but did not found the parameters.
